# TYPO3 extbase: order dates by month and day (ignore year)

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have a database containing birthdates. I want to display the next birthdays from now. However, I'm not sure what would be the simplest way to do this. I cannot simply sort the dates, since I need to ignore the year of the date.

Actually, info the action controller, I fetch all the objects from the repository, I extract month and day, I put all data into an array, then I sort the array according to month and day. I was wondering if there would be an easier way to perform this task.

Answer (score 1):

see how I do it in my [TYPO3 news extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news), https://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Extensions/news.git/blob/HEAD:/Classes/Domain/Repository/NewsRepository.php#l360

Comment: Yes, using SQL directly is an idea. However, doesn't it break database abstraction?

Comment: Really depends how you do it